# How can I set the energy settings for the Radioactivity module?

Tags: 7

I saw in [this screencast](http://vimeo.com/9337149) (from 4m 20s) that a lot of cool features were available to set the energy settings in Drupal 6. One could for example give specific scores when nodes were viewed or evaluated with Fivestar.

Is this possible in Drupal 7 too? I can't find any documentation about it...

[image: The energy settings in Drupal 6]

Comment: Aren't they applied by Rules in Drupal 7? Or maybe on the field settings (you attach a Radioactivity field to an entity if I remember rightly)

Comment: @Clive: One can indeed add some settings to a Radioactivity field, but these ones don't cover what I'm looking for. Should I really add a rule for every energy setting? Strange evolution from the module, regarding easy usability...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All those cool features are still there, you just need to set up a "Decay profile". You can do this at /admin/structure/radioactivity.

Once you've got the profile setup (with the "Advanced" method by the sounds of what you're looking for), you can edit the Radioactivity field on the entity, and choose that profile. When the entity is viewed, the tracking will kick in automatically.

To respond to events such as fivestar ratings, you need to use the Rules module as everything's been decoupled for flexbility.

Comment: @Jeroen I recorded a [screencast](http://youtu.be/vxXeJASe-QM) about a year ago over Radioactivity that covers the basics in the Drupal 7 version. Hope it helps!